# Anchor tag is adding a path to my id link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a user control which contains a link, when it is clicked I want to open a nav as a popup menu. I'm using jQuery mobile and I've given my nav an id, and the link points to it as required.

This works without any issues on one page, but when I add the control to another page it changes the href attribute on the link to "Controls/#menu" and instead of opening the div, it will try to redirect (and shows the Controls directory).

HTML:

```
<a id="lnkMenu" runat="server" href="#menu" data-rel="popup" data-icon="grid"
data-iconpos="right" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window">Menu</a>

<nav id="menu" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-count-theme="b">
        <!-- Some <li>s with menu options -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I load the page:

```
<a data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="right"
data-icon="grid" data-rel="popup" id="ctl00_Banner2_mobileProfileMenu_lnkMenu"
href="Controls/#menu" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all
ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" aria-haspopup="true"
aria-owns="Controls/#menu">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Menu</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I am using:

- jQuery 1.10.2
- jQuery UI 1.10.3
- jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

As far as I can tell, there's no custom javascript that's modifying the control, and I have got this working in one place, it's just breaking elsewhere. The only difference between the 2 pages is that where it works I am not using jQuery UI. If I manually edit the page (using firebug or chrome dev tools for example) to fix the href, it works as expected.

In case it's relevant, the user control is being used in a page in another directory, with a master page in the site's root directory. All the javascript is loaded on the master page.

EDIT: I tried removing jQuery UI from the problem page and the issue persists.

Comment: It appears you're using ASP.NET, which will sometimes change the generated href attribute for some server controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing some custom javascript AND removing jQuery UI I was able to get the popup working (the custom javascript was using jQuery UI). The href still seems to add the path to the link, but it's working, so I guess that's a win.

If anyone else ends up having this problem, try removing jQuery UI. I have a feeling it doesn't play nice with jQuery Mobile.